# ImpersonationLevel is still Impersonation instead of Delegation even with SPNs and allowing delegation on the machine

Tags: c#, .net, iis, spn, kerberos-delegation

ImpersonationLevel on my WindowsIdentity is still Impersonation instead of Delegation even with SPNs and permitting Kerberos delegation on the machine.

I have the exact same setup in development, where I also double hop to the development server.
I'm trying to publish this to the live server, but I keep getting impersonation errors, where I cannot get the imperosnation level to be 'Delegation'

What else is there to do? Debugging Kerberos seems impossible -- is there a way to see which SPNs it is checking for?